# power shell active directory script

Tags: scripting, powershell, active-directory

I need a power shell script that will move OU's based on a xlsx file.

Also I was wondering if there is a way to remove a member of the OU and to add a member below it with out knowing it's name.

Example after I do the moving of the OU's I need to give the TOP OU control of all the OU's under it by making it a member of the OU's.

powershell v1 I believe it's a 2008 server

I could also use VB but I dont know how to program in VB.

Comment: your question is not clear enough, how is your xls file ? what do you really want to do ? What do you test ?

Answer (score 1):

Quest has made working with Active Directory with Powershell easier with their AD cmdlets. You can download them [here](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx). They allow you to manipulate most everything in AD with Powershell.

To work with data from an Excel spreadsheet use the com object:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

Excel API documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978780%28v=office.12%29.aspx).